# Fourier Transform of Cauchy Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was wondering what the Fourier Transform of the density of a Cauchy random variable is, with PDF $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\gamma}{(x-x_0)^2+\gamma^2}$. Also, what's the Fourier Transform of a normal random variable?

I'm trying to compute the Fourier transform of the convolution of these densities, then try to apply an inverse Fourier transform. I basically need a PDF for the sum of a Cauchy and Normal random variable, in a form that isn't just the integral/convolution.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just work with the characteristic functions?

Comment: Could you give me intuition on how to start? I'm game to do anything that's going to give me a PDF for that sum :)

Comment: Check Wikipedia's entries for Cauchy and Normal. Both include their characteristic function which get multiplied when two independent variables are added together.

Comment: @Joe It is mostly a matter of semantics. The characteristic function is defined as the inverse Fourier transform, much like the cumulative distribution function could be defined in terms of a nonincreasing, left-continuous function - the theory would be equvalent. But in the latter case, I think you can see why no one does that ;)

Comment: So if I have the characteristic function of the sum, what's the best way to get the probability density function of the sum? Or the CDF? Theoretically, I want to show the CDF of the sum is a decreasing function in a variable, so I need an expression for it.

Comment: (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I have to take the Fourier Transform of that)